# Which is the best COVID-19 booster dose for a patient in their forties?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

The Iranian government now recommends booster doses for those 40 years old or older. Most people in Iran were vaccinated with Sinopharm. For a booster, they can choose between Sinopharm, Astrazenk, Pastocovac (soberana 2), Sputnik V, COVIran Barekat and SpikoGen.
Is [SpikoGen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVAX-19) a good choice from that list for a booster dose? How about [Soberana Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soberana_Plus) ?
I heard that Astrazenk may be harmful for those under fifty.

Answer (score -1):

The best vaccine is the one you can get. This is such a cliche that a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=the%20best%20vaccine%20is%20the%20one%20you%20can%20get&ia=web) for it reveals pages of results, from a variety of experts in a variety of places.

If you have or know children, ask yourself what brand of MMR vaccine they got, or TDAP, or any other childhood vaccine. If you ever got a tetanus shot after an injury, what brand was that? You don't know, and you don't care, because you trusted the doctor or nurse who administered it to choose well, from among those a government agency has tested and approved.

If a particular vaccine is in fact less safe for a particular age group, your medical practitioner is going to know that. There will be some sort of memo suggesting to avoid it for that age group. You don't need to take on that work.

Comment: As far as I know, MMRs and TDAPs are pretty much interchangeable in terms of efficacy.  That's very much not true for COVID-19 vaccines: for example, the AstraZeneca vaccine is 10% effective against the Beta variant, the Janssen vaccine is 64% effective, and the Moderna vaccine is 88% effective.

Comment: well a, Beta isn't really the issue now, and b, neither Janssen nor Moderna is being offered to the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry Kate, but this answer could not be more wrong! Just because Justin Trudeau said "The best vaccine is the first vaccine" doesn't mean it's correct, in fact  Canada stopped issuing the Oxford-AstraZeneca vaccine shortly after! The fact that something is "cliche" and reveals many search results, is not actually the standard we seek in medical science. There's plenty of anti-vax search results that are cliche too. Then you act like what applies for MMR does for COVID. It isn't just about "brand" it's about the technology: HP vs Samsung computer doesn't matter but laptop vs desktop does!

Comment: "You don't need to take on that work" - Excuse me? The purpose of this site is for people who want to learn about medical science. A major aspect of learning science is asking questions and seeking answers. Trusting the "memo" is not the way to learn science, and would actually lead you to the wrong answer such as "the best vaccine is the first vaccine". Furthermore, with medical practitioners  being influenced strongly by politics, now more than ever it's important to do research if you want to know something. The point of this site is to help people learn medical science, a valuable thing.